# Optimizing a mySQL query with functions

Tags: mysql

I'm running this query (via PHP) and wondering if there is a faster way to get the same result:

```
SELECT 
    date(date_time) as `date`, 
    unix_timestamp(date(date_time)) as `timestamp`, 
    month(date(date_time)) as `month`, 
    dayname(date(date_time)) as `dayname`, 
    dayofmonth(date(date_time)) as `daynum`, 
    hour(date_time) as `hour`, minute(date_time) as `increment`
FROM loc_data 
WHERE loc_id = 2
```

As you can see I'm performing the `date(date_time)` function 5 times but would like to store the result of the first and use that result from then on. Would this increase performance of the query? The query is called many thousands of times in a script. (When I perform the functions in PHP instead of mySQL I get no big difference in speed from the current query above.)

Comment: Why is the query called thousands of times? If you're using it in a loop, you should look at refactoring your query using a `JOIN`, if possible.

Comment: Regardless of the design I would still like to know if I can use the result of the first function in the rest of the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with `SQL variables`?

```
select @a from (select @a := 1) a
```

That works, with your query

```
SELECT 
    @n as `date`, 
    unix_timestamp(@n) as `timestamp`
FROM loc_data l,
     (select @n := date(l.date_time)) a 
WHERE l.loc_id = 2
```

But I'm not sure if this will work for you.